# Limit on array size for fftw using Eclipse and mingw?

Tags: c, eclipse, mingw, fftw

I am trying to use the FFTW .dll (v 3.3.3) in a C program on a Windows 8 system using Eclipse (Kepler) and MinGW (gcc 4.7.2). There are two issues which I suspect are to do with my configuration:

1. With an array size of less than 977, the program runs and produces the
   expected output; if N>= 977 the program crashes with no output.
2. Although running with N<977 gives expected output, debugging gives values that are completely different.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complexUtil.h>
#include <fftw3.h>

#define N 976

main()
{
    fftw_complex *in, *out;
    fftw_plan p;

    in =  (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
    out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);

    FILE* infile;
    float value;
    int i = 0;

    // Populate input array from file
    infile = fopen("testData.txt", "r");
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
        fscanf(infile, "%f", &value);
        (*(in + i)) = value + 0.0i;
    }
    fclose(infile);

    // Perform fft
    p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(p);
    fftw_destroy_plan(p);
    fftw_free(in); fftw_free(out);

    // Debug output
    printf("in\t\tout\n");
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
        printf("%f\t%f\n", 
                   creal((fftw_complex)* (in + i )), 
                   creal((fftw_complex)* (out + i )));
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Compiler calls:

```
gcc "-IC:\\Users\\Brian\\workspace\\psd\\src" "-IC:\\Users\\Brian\\workspace\\psd\\lib" "-includeC:\\Users\\Brian\\workspace\\psd\\src\\complexUtil.h" "-includeC:\\Users\\Brian\\workspace\\psd\\src\\fftw3.h" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\psd.o" "..\\src\\psd.c" 
gcc "-LC:\\Users\\Brian\\workspace\\psd\\lib" -Wl,--stack,2048 -o psd.exe "src\\psd.o" -lfftw3-3
```

Normal output:

```
in          out
0.188000    348.455000
0.000000    29.738027
0.021000    -88.468551
0.021000    16.764387
0.021000    -48.056287
...
```

Debug output:

```
in          out
-2656984258037080400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000    -2656984258037080400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
-2656984258037080400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000    -2656984258037080400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
...
```

One further symptom: in debug mode no output is shown as I am stepping through until a certain number of iterations through the output loop. Then I get a block of output and the stepping functions in Eclipse are grayed out.

Comment: ***`int`*** `main()`...

Comment: @H2CO3 comment has nothing to do with problem.

Answer (score 0):

977 is prime and so it doesn't factorise into powers of small primes as required by FFTW. So `fftw_plan_dft_1d` will fail and return NULL, and any subsequent calls to FFTW with p == NULL will of course crash. If you try a sensible value for N > 976, e.g. N = 1024, then that should work as expected, as your code appears to be OK (apart from a complete lack of error checking).

Comment: Thanks Paul. I already tried 1024 with the same result. I arrived at 977 by working downwards to find the value where the problem began. Re error checking - quite right MBR$

Comment: Possibly not relevant but unless you really need double precision then consider using the single precision libraries and headers (fftw3f) - it will be faster and it will halve your memory requirements.

Comment: Actually that was an earlier problem which I worked around by using the double precision library. With fftw3f-3 I got this: gcc "-LC:\\Users\\Brian\\workspace\\psd\\lib" -Wl,--stack,2048 -o psd.exe "src\\psd.o" -lfftw3f-3 
src\psd.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\Brian\workspace\psd\Debug/../src/psd.c:23: undefined reference to `_imp__fftw_malloc'
C:\Users\Brian\workspace\psd\Debug/../src/psd.c:24: undefined reference to `_imp__fftw_malloc'

Comment: Sounds like you're having a run of bad luck with FFTW - you may be right about this being something to do with your configuration as FFTW is generally pretty much trouble-free on Linux/OS X/Windows in my experience (although FWIW the only bug I ever found in FFTW happened only in the Windows build).

Comment: Turned out to be a dumb mistake. The solution was moving the calls to fftw_free *after* the statements that print the debug output. D'oh!

Comment: Heh - I hadn't spotted that, but I see it now!